# history.listen not triggered on back button action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, listener, browser-history

I read online that I can use `history.listen` to respond to changes in the URL. I'm wanting to dispatch different React actions when the back or forward buttons are clicked.

From here https://github.com/ReactTraining/history I tried

```
history.listen(( location, action) => {
   // some code
});
```

but the callback here doesn't fire when the forward or back button are pressed.

Comment: are you using react-router ? which version

Comment: Yes v4 with `HashRouter`